# Conditional Variable doesn't wake up

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have to build a pizzeria in c++ for a school project. In order to do that I have to use thread and CondVar. I'm doing this for Condvar:

```
class Condvar
{
  pthread_cond_t m_cond_var;
  Mutex _mut;
public:
  Condvar()
  {
    _mut.init();
    pthread_cond_init(&m_cond_var, NULL);
  }
  ~Condvar()
  {
    pthread_cond_destroy(&m_cond_var);
  }
  void wait()
  {
    _mut.lock();
    pthread_cond_wait(&m_cond_var, _mut.getMutex());
    _mut.unlock();
  }
  void signal()
  {
    pthread_cond_signal(&m_cond_var);
  }
  void broadcast()
  {
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&m_cond_var);
  }
};
```

The Constructor of my Kitchen:

```
Kitchen::Kitchen(int nb_cooks, float mult, int time_ing):_nb_cooks(nb_cooks), _mult(mult), _time_ing(time_ing)
{
  int   i = 0;
  _pipe = new PipeClass();
  _fork = new Fork();
  if (_fork->isSon())
    {
      _pipe->setSon(true);
      _run = true;
      _cond = new Condvar();
      _stock.push_back(new Mushrooms(5));

      cook_mutex.init();
      ingr_mutex.init();
      while (i < _nb_cooks)
        {
          _cooks.push_back(new Cook(mult, _pizzaList, *_cond, cook_mutex));
          i++;
        }
      _thread = new Thread(this);
      run();
    }
  else
    _pipe->setSon(false);
}
```

I build my Pizza:

```
void    Kitchen::doPizza()
{
  PizzaGenerator        gen;
  std::string   order;
  APizza        *pizza;
  std::vector<AIngredient *>pizzaIngr;
  bool  check;

  std::cout << "I do the pizza" << std::endl;
  order = _pipe->getline();
  pizza = gen.createForKitchen(order);
  pizzaIngr = pizza->getIngredients();
  if ((check = checkIngredients(pizzaIngr)) == false)
    _pipe->write("KO");
  else if (checkCooks() + _pizzaList.size() <= (unsigned int)(2 * _nb_cooks))
    {
      removeIngredientsFromStock(pizzaIngr);
      _pizzaList.push_back(pizza);
      std::cout << "JE RENTRE DEDANS" << std::endl;
      _cond->signal();
      _pipe->write("OK");
    }
}
```

And the run of my Cook:

```
void    *Cook::run()
{
  while (!_stop)
    {
      if (_pizzaList.size() != 0)
        std::cout << "I CAN COOK" << std::endl;
      if (!_stop)
        _cond.wait();
    }
  return NULL;
}
```

But my condvar doesn't act.

Comment: Firstly, use C++ threads and associated utility classes. Then, check returnvalues for errors in case you still want to use POSIX threads. If that doesn't give you any insight, provide a minimal but still complete example.  BTW: Why does the `Mutex` class have an `init()` function? That belongs in the constructor, I would say.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I can't use C++ threads I'm not allox to do that .. Check my edit

Comment: I understand your limitation, but your edit still doesn't consider my other points, in particular I can't even compile that code. Please meditate about the meaning of "complete" and "minimal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
_mut.lock();
pthread_cond_wait(&m_cond_var, _mut.getMutex());
_mut.unlock();
```

fundamentally misunderstands how pthreads condition variables work.  The mutex argument to `pthread_cond_wait()` isn't just there to be an embuggerance: a condition variable must be paired with a condition over some shared state (often called a *predicate*), and the mutex passed should be the mutex that protects that shared state.

In other words, you should use `pthread_cond_wait()` something very much like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
/* ... */
while (!condition)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

/* 'condition' is now true, and mutex is held.  Do some operation here that
 * depends upon 'condition' being true. */

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

In this case, it looks like the condition that the cooks wait for might be "there is at least one pizza waiting to be cooked, or the stop flag has been set".  The cooks then need to call code along these lines:

```
pizzalist_mutex.lock();

do {
    while (_pizzaList.size() == 0 && !stop)
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, pizzalist_mutex.getMutex());

    if (_pizzaList.size() != 0)
    {
        /* remove pizza from pizza list */
        pizzalist_mutex.unlock();
        /* cook pizza */
        pizzalist_mutex.lock();
    }
} while (!stop);

pizzalist_mutex.unlock();
```

...where `pizzalist_mutex` is a mutex is that used to protect the pizzaList and the global `stop`.

It would perhaps make sense to implement this "wait for a pizza from the pizza list" as a method of the pizza list object itself.